How to store origin depth values in depth attachment?
I am trying to implement rendering points on top of geometry as in Blender. The algorithm is as follows: rendering is done through PointList without depth test. The depth test is done manually in the shader. We have a point. (Let's say a 5x5 square). And I compare the depth of the center of this square (vertex depth) with the depth of the scene. I get the scene depth through the depth texture sampler.
I am facing a problem while comparing the depth. The data doesn't add up.
Here is an example of the most common case:
Depth from texture: 0.978166640
NDC depth: 0.978173256

I realize that this problem can be solved in principle by adding epsilon, but in some cases the difference in comparison is significant:
Depth from texture: 0.616887
NDC depth: 0.622718

This is where the 2nd digit differs.
In the sampler I tried using both linear filtering and nearest filtering. At first I thought it was the sampler. First of all, I made an additional color attachment in which I manually entered gl_FragCoord.z additionally logging the values that are added. And I found out that the values in the manual color attachment are the same as in the normal depth. And the values in gl_FragCoord.z are the same as in manual depth calculation. So the problem is obviously not in the calculations. Secondly, I opened my project in RenderDoc and looked at the output depth of the scene. Unfortunately, RenderDoc rounds values. So I exported the texture as a raw data buffer. Looked at the values per pixel and found that the values are about the same as what I get through the sampler. I emphasize that I was not looking at the sampled image, but at the output depth buffer.
I also tried temporarily (as part of testing) to use input attachments instead of sampler to eliminate such reasons as sampling and interpolation of data when accessing through UV. Still the data is different.
It turns out that when writing the data is one, but in the texture itself they are mixed. Depth texture format: D32SFLOAT. But I have tried other ones.
So far I have an idea to store SSBO buffer and manually fill it, but I don't think it's optimal.
The question is: is there any way to provide the same values when forming the depth texture as the original ones?
Example code:
#version 460

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
#extension GL_EXT_debug_printf : enable

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform CameraUBO {
  mat4 projection;
  mat4 view;
} camera;

layout(push_constant) uniform Push {
  mat4 model;
} mesh;

layout(set = 1, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D sDepth;

layout(location = 0) flat out uint visible;

void main() {
  gl_Position = camera.projection * camera.view * mesh.model * vec4(position, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 1;
  vec3 ndc = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w;
  vec2 uv = ndc.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
  ivec2 texelCoord = ivec2(uv * textureSize(sDepth, 0));
  float depth = texelFetch(sDepth, texelCoord, 0).r;
  if (ndc.z <= depth) visible = 1;
  else
  {
    visible = 0;
    debugPrintfEXT("[Vertex, Points] Depth: %.9f, NDC: %.9f\n", depth, ndc.z);
  }
}

I would also like to add that I do not certify that my hike is correct. I will be glad to receive any other ideas on realization of point rendering.
UPD: I temporarily changed topology from TriangleList to PointList in the first render pass (scene rendering). As a result of the change, the depth values became identical to ndc coordinates. I.e. the problem occurs when rasterizing triangles.
I provide the code of rasterization settings. The structure is based on vulkan-hpp:
PipelineConfig defaultPipelineConfig()
{
    PipelineConfig config;
    config.inputAssemblyInfo.setTopology(vk::PrimitiveTopology::eTriangleList).setPrimitiveRestartEnable(false);
    config.viewportInfo.setViewportCount(1).setScissorCount(1);
    config.rasterizationInfo.setDepthClampEnable(false)
        .setRasterizerDiscardEnable(false)
        .setPolygonMode(vk::PolygonMode::eFill)
        .setLineWidth(1.0f)
        .setCullMode(vk::CullModeFlagBits::eNone)
        .setFrontFace(vk::FrontFace::eClockwise)
        .setDepthBiasEnable(false);

    config.colorBlendAttachment
        .setColorWriteMask(vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eR | // Red
                           vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eG | // Green
                           vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eB | // Blue
                           vk::ColorComponentFlagBits::eA)  // Alpha
        .setBlendEnable(false);
    config.colorBlendInfo.setLogicOpEnable(false).setAttachmentCount(1).setPAttachments(&config.colorBlendAttachment);
    config.depthStencilInfo.setDepthTestEnable(true)
        .setDepthWriteEnable(true)
        .setDepthCompareOp(vk::CompareOp::eLess)
        .setDepthBoundsTestEnable(false);
    config.dynamicStateEnables = {vk::DynamicState::eViewport, vk::DynamicState::eScissor};
    config.dynamicStateInfo.setPDynamicStates(config.dynamicStateEnables.data())
        .setDynamicStateCount(config.dynamicStateEnables.size())
        .setFlags(vk::PipelineDynamicStateCreateFlags());
    return config;
}

UPD2:
I think I have a theory as to why this happens. Take a look at the screenshot from the article. Using PointList we actually have rasterization like in Wireframe, but without edges. Here, each pixel of the output attachment corresponds to a vertex position. With default settings, pixels are painted inside the triangle and the pixel that corresponds to the vertex will not always be painted. Therefore, I use PipelineRasterizationConservativeStateCreateInfoEXT. But let's look again at the variant with solid geometry and using Conservative Rasterizaion. Here also, the pixel to be painted may not always correspond to the vertex. It may be higher. And it turns out that interpolation starts a bit higher than the actual position of the vertex. That's why the values don't converge when accessing ndc.
Any ideas how to get correct depth data?

Just to rule out your final hypothesis, have you actually tried turning off conservative rasterization to see if it helps? AFAIK it shouldn't impact Z values if all verts have the same Z value.

@solidpixel Yeah. The values don't add up either. I think it's the opposite problem. If in the case of conservative rasterization the initial pixel was one more than the actual vertex position, here it is the opposite - the pixel is one less than the actual vertex. And here we have the same interpolation problems.  Besides, there is a problem on the contour of the object. The value 1.0 (ClearValue) is obtained. This is because the pixels are drawn just below the contour. You can see it in the picture.

@solidpixel Frankly speaking I think it is not a technical problem. I think it's a matter of approach. But this is not a trivial task. So I decided to ask here.
So far I have the following idea: I can make a pre-render to a separate texture with points or edges to ensure that the depth will be correct. And in the 2nd pass get the value from this texture. But this is also one more rendering of objects. So far I haven't thought of anything better.

I think I've figured it out. To make a long story short, it seems you can't do that. Let me explain:
I checked again in Cinema 4D and Blender. First of all, I increased the size of points and noticed that in these programs whole points are not rendered. Some vertex fragments are also cut off by depth.

Secondly, when you move away vertices that should be hidden appear, which by the way leads to incorrect vertex selection in both programs.

From here I can conclude that here is just added epsilon to ensure that visible vertices will be on top of the geometry.
I think it won't work because of the difference in rasterization. Let's imagine that we have 2 render passes. In the first one we fill the depth. In the second one we read.

Fill - Points:
As I wrote in my question, by default the point goes along the fragments contour, and triangles inside the contour.



 Triangle rasterisation
 Estimated point

You can enable conservative rasterization, but then the opposite situation will happen and the triangle fragments will be above the contour. Because of the offset of the start of interpolation, the depth will also not be as expected.


 Triangle rasterisation
 Estimated point


Lines - Points:
I tried rendering the Wireframe depth into a separate texture and again encountered problems. It turned out that here too there is no guarantee that the vertex will be located exactly on the triangle's edge.



 Triangle rasterisation
 Estimated point


Points - Points:
I managed to find a linear relationship between the different scenes and the expected epsilon. It turns out that it decreases in progression depending on near/far planes. But it works only when using conservative rasterization. Without it, some of the points are hidden. I followed this option, but the depth was still not converging. I opened my project in RenderDoc and saw why.



 Actual vertex position
 Point fragments

When using conservative rasterization, four pixels are painted instead of one. This is the reason why it doesn't work without conservative rasterization. And for the same reason the depth doesn't converge. Because the actual pixel does not fall within that square.
I decided to do like Cinema4D and Blender. I added epsilon (depth offset) and use one pass to render points.
Current code:
#version 460

// clang-format off

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform CameraInfo
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 viewInverse;
    float near;
    float far;
} camera;

layout(push_constant) uniform Push { mat4 modelMatrix; };

// clang-format on

void main()
{
    gl_Position = camera.projection * camera.view * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position.z -= 4e-3 * camera.near;
    gl_PointSize = 4;
}


